# sequelize remote database access

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database that i have previously been accessing (using php) remotely now i am trying to setup sequelize to connect to the same remote servers database:

for this i have the following `json` (database.json):

```
{
  "dev": {
    "server": "serverip",
    "driver": "mysql",
    "user": "username",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "databasename",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

(ive excluded sensitive data)

Now the way i connect to the database from my `server.js` is:

```
    var env = app.get('env') == 'development' ? 'dev' : app.get('env');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// db config
var env = "dev";
var config = require('./database.json')[env];
var password = config.password ? config.password : null;

// initialize database connection
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.server,
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.port,
    config.password,
    {
        logging: console.log,
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        }
    }
);
```

The "sad" thing about this is that i does not throw any errors but i know it is not connected because it does not collect any data from the database.

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the API docs for creating a new sequelize instance: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/

Only database, user and password should passed as arguments, the rest is in the options object.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        port: config.port,
        host: config.server,
        logging: console.log,
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        }    
    }
);
```

Comment: Hey again @Jan ive passed the variables you suggest however it still does not connect

Comment: What happens when you try to run a query then? You must be getting some kind of error message?

Comment: No error messages all i get it "something is happening"

Comment: What do you mean you get  "something is happening" - is that message printed to the console? That does not come from sequelize code, I can asure you.

Comment: Yeah i noticed but it doesnt give me any errors while connecting nor trying to access any of the models :s its kinda odd

Comment: Well, sequelize does actually connect to the DB before you make a query - what happens if you call `find` on your of your models. Either the query succeeds, or it throws an error :). Also, we are getting into a long comment discussion again - Try to join the #sequelizejs IRC channel on freenode and ask your question there instead

Comment: i found an error message which is kinda odd ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'109.56.7.58' (using password: YES) the problem is that the ip is not the one i instered into the server variable???

Comment: How can you get the model's instance of a table that is already in a remote database. Im able to connect to a remote db. But instead of directly using query method to write extensive sql queries, can I use the ORM like functionality to query data from an existing table without defining the model in my node app?